# How to run a continuous loop in javascript

Tags: javascript, while-loop, sentinel

```
while(userInput!= -1)
{ 
    var total=0.0;
    var totalEarnings=0;
    var item;
    //var userInput;
    var salesPerson=1; 
    var  userInput= parseInt(prompt("outsidePlease enter noOfItemsSold of Item# 1 sold for SalesPerson #"+salesPerson+"\n"+" OR -1 to Exit "));
    salesPerson++;
    //alert("in while "+salesPerson);
    //userInput= parseInt(prompt("Please enter noOfItemsSold of Item# "+item+" sold for SalesPerson #"+salesPerson+"\n"+" OR -1 to Exit "));
    //if(userInput!=-1)
    //{ 
    for(item=2;item<5;item++)
    {
        //userInput= parseInt(prompt("Please enter noOfItemsSold of Item# "+item+" sold for SalesPerson #"+salesPerson+"\n"+" OR -1 to Exit "));

        //var noOfItemsSold = parseInt( userInput);

         if ( item == 1 )
         {
            total += userInput * 239.99;
         }
         else if (item == 2 )
         {
            total += userInput * 129.75;
         }
         else if ( item == 3 )
         {
            total += userInput * 99.95;
         }
         else if ( item == 4 )
         {
            total += userInput * 350.89;
         }
         var input= parseInt(prompt("Please enter noOfItemsSold of Item# "+item+" sold for SalesPerson #"+salesPerson+"\n"+" OR -1 to Exit "));
    }
    totalEarnings = .09 * total + 200;
    document.writeln( "<h1>SalesPerson#"+salesPerson+" Total Earnings this week is  " +totalEarnings +"</h1>" );   
}
```

I am trying to run the continuous loop. Script is calculating the total earnings of salesperson, and I want to run the script till the user enter -1.
I don't know what I am doing wrong but this is not working.
How can I fix this?

Comment: I think you may need to instantiate userInput outside the while loop rather than inside it.

Comment: When you say *this is not working*, can you be more specific?

Comment: @Bob - I think variable hoisting will actually let that work, but I agree it's sloppy heh.

Comment: Look at your `var` declarations. They're inside the loop. That means that you're re-declaring those variables for every iteration of the loop. You should declare them *before* the loop.

Fixing this doesn't solve your problem, but it should be cleaned up anyway.

Comment: You should always include the radix argument when using [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt). You should also use the triple-equals equality and inequality symbols whenever you do comparisons in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

```
while (1) {


   if (condition met) {
       break;
   } 
}
```

your loop will always be true until your conditional test (insert yours is true) and then it will break and go on to the rest of your code.

Comment: That's exactly what `while ( condition )` *does*. You've just moved the condition test to the bottom of the `while` block, instead of evaluating it at the beginning of the next loop. That'll work, but it gains you nothing, and costs you readability. The poster's underlying problem is that he's not testing the right condition in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, the condition isn't evaluated until after the iteration of the loop has completed.  So, if the user types in `-1`, the `for` loop will still be executed which is probably not what you want.

I suggest using the `break;` keyword to exit the loop.  Trying something like this:

```
while(true) // Loop forever, since we'll break manually
{ 
  var total = 0.0;
  var totalEarnings = 0;
  var item;
  var salesPerson = 1;
  var userInput = parseInt(prompt("outsidePlease enter noOfItemsSold of Item# 1 sold for SalesPerson #"+salesPerson+"\n"+" OR -1 to Exit "));
  salesPerson++;

  if(userInput == -1) // Exit immediately!
     break;

  for(item=2;item<5;item++)
  {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've cleaned up the code a bit:

```
var total;
var totalEarnings;
var item;
var salesPerson;
var userInput;
var input;

while ( userInput != -1 ) { 

    total = 0.0;
    totalEarnings = 0;
    salesPerson = 1;
    userInput = parseInt( prompt( "outsidePlease enter noOfItemsSold of Item# 1 sold for SalesPerson #" + salesPerson + "\n OR -1 to Exit" ), 10 );
    salesPerson++;

    for ( item = 2; item < 5; item++ ) {

         if ( item == 1 ) {
            total += userInput * 239.99;
         } else if (item == 2 ) {
            total += userInput * 129.75;
         } else if ( item == 3 ) {
            total += userInput * 99.95;
         } else if ( item == 4 ) {
            total += userInput * 350.89;
         }
         input = parseInt( prompt( "Please enter noOfItemsSold of Item# " + item + " sold for SalesPerson #" + salesPerson + "\n OR -1 to Exit" ) );

    }

    totalEarnings = .09 * total + 200;
    document.writeln( "<h1>SalesPerson#" + salesPerson + " Total Earnings this week is " + totalEarnings + "</h1>" );

}
```

Your loop will repeat as long as userInput has a value other than -1.

Now let's look at what each iteration of the loop does:

1. It assigns some initial values to a few variables.
2. It prompts the user to input a value; that value is assigned to `userInput`.
3. It then (rather bizarrely) repeats a similar prompt to the user, this time assigning them to `input` (*not* `userInput`) and using them to perform calculations for `total`.

The only time `userInput` is ever assigned a value is in step 2:

```
userInput = parseInt( prompt( "outsidePlease enter noOfItemsSold of Item# 1 sold for SalesPerson #" + salesPerson + "\n OR -1 to Exit" ), 10 );
```

And if you enter -1 as your input here, the loop `will` terminate, just as expected.

Comment: my method does the calculations for one person and without running the program again i want to run my loop for second person with all variables initialized to initial values, so i have declared them inside the while loop but even though user enter -1 in this statement its not exiting the loop userInput = parseInt( prompt( "outsidePlease enter noOfItemsSold of Item# 1 sold for SalesPerson #" + salesPerson + "\n OR -1 to Exit" ), 10 );

Comment: "even though user enter -1 in this statement its not exiting the loop"

That is not true. If you enter -1 as *the very first number*, then it *does* exit the loop.

That's because the first prompt is the only time you're actually assigning a value to `userInput`. The values of subsequent prompts are being assigned to `input`, which is a different variable and is not being checked by your `while` condition.

There's quite a bit else that's wrong with this code, though. For instance, there's no need to call prompt() separately the first time, then use a loop to call it the next three times.